# R ddply sum value from next row

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I want to sum the column value from a row with the next one.

```
> df

+----+------+--------+------+
| id |  Val | Factor | Col  |
+----+------+--------+------+
|  1 |   15 |      1 |    7 |
|  3 |   20 |      1 |    4 |
|  2 |   35 |      2 |    8 | 
|  7 |   35 |      1 |   12 |
|  5 |   40 |      1 |   11 |
|  6 |   45 |      2 |   13 |
|  4 |   55 |      1 |    4 |
|  8 |   60 |      1 |    7 |
|  9 |   15 |      2 |   12 |
..........
```

I would like to have the mean of sum of the `Row$Val` + `nextRow$Val` based on their `id` and `Col`. I can't assume that the `id` or `Col` are consecutive.

I am using ddply to summarize my df. I have tried

```
> ddply(df, .(Factor), summarize, 
       max(Val), 
       sum(Val), 
       mean(Val + df[df$id == id+1 & df$Col = Col]$Val)
       )

> "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

Comment: Careful, if you sum before you take the mean, you're just returning the sum. `mean` takes something like `mean(c(3, 5))`. Alternately, just manually divide by 2 after you sum.

Comment: Just shift the values by one.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you. It is good to know. Any suggestion on how to solve the question?

Comment: @DavidArenburg could you expend on that?

Comment: Something like `x <- 1:10 ; (head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1))/2` (using some mock data). If you want by group you use `ave` with it. Or could use `lag` from `dplyr` combined with `group_by`, or `shift` from `data.table` combined with `by`. I'm sure there are plenty of these on SO.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The id are unique but can't assume that the id are consecutive.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Just order by `id`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I made the appropriate edit. I made some changes to the questions. I can't only rely on ordering.

Comment: Maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(DT)[, .(Max = max(Val), Sum = sum(Val), Mean = mean(c(Val, shift(Val, type = "lead")), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(id, Col)]` (assuming `DT` is your data set)? Though this is pretty much what I already offered before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package. Since you want mean of only two consecutive rows , you can try

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(df[order(df$id), 2], 2, function(x) sum(x)/2)

#[1] 17.5 27.5 35.0 37.5 42.5 50.0 57.5 37.5
```

Comment: It's a simplified example. I can't assume they are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a vector of values with

```
sapply(df$id, function(x){mean(c(
    subset(df, id == x, select = Val, drop = TRUE), 
    subset(df, id == x+1, select = Val, drop = TRUE)
    ))})
```

You could simplify, but I tried to make it as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- arrange(df, id)
mean(df$Val + lead(df$Val), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 76.25
```